# Combining reCAPTCHA v2 and v3

Tags: recaptcha

I'm keen to use reCAPTCHA v3 for logins and stuff, but I'm unsure what to do with a 'low rating', it doesn't feel safe to deny access with no way for the user to move forward. What feels like a more complete solution would be to combine the "rating" from v3 with a puzzle challenge from v2 if the score is too low. How are other people approaching this issue?

Also, it appears that v3's `grecaptcha.execute` returns a similar result to v2, that is too say that it's not returning a rating, just a `TOKEN` which is verified in a similar way to v2?

I've code i found to demonstrate that they can both be used in the same HTML...

```html
<!-- https://github.com/google/recaptcha/issues/279 -->
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=v2_onload"></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=v3_onload&render=V3_SITE_KEY"></script>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=V3_SITE_KEY'></script>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-size="invisible" data-sitekey="V2_SITE_KEY" data-callback="v2_callback"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function v2_onload() { console.log('v2 loaded'); }
    function v3_onload() { console.log('v3 loaded'); }
    function v2_callback(token) { console.log('v2 token: ' + token); }
    function v3_callback(token, score) { console.log('v3 token: ' + token +    " ----- " + score); }

    // call these manually
    function test_v2() { grecaptcha.execute(); }
    function test_v3() { 
    grecaptcha.execute('V3_SITE_KEY' , {action:'thisIsATest' }).then(v3_callback); 
}
```

I have concerns then that if v3 requires sever-side validation, in order to implement v2 as well, either a page reload to invoke v2 (when server-side says "low rating" then reload and enable v2) OR v3 sever-side validation could be done via an ajax call, but that feels like something that can be inspected and manipulated by a bot (grab ajax response, change 'no' to 'yes' and then have the bot call the 'callback' function itself to gain access).

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like there is an answer to this question on the official *Frequently Asked Questions* website of *reCAPTCHA*.

[Can I run *reCAPTCHA* *v2* and *v3* on the same page?](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#can-i-run-recaptcha-v2-and-v3-on-the-same-page)

> To do this, load the *v3* site key as [documented](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3), and then explicitly render *v2* using `grecaptcha.render`.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>reCAPTCHA demo: Running both v2 and v3</title>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=v3_site_key"></script>
    <script>
      grecaptcha.ready(() => {
        grecaptcha.render('html_element', {
           'sitekey' : 'v2_site_key'
        });
      });
    </script>
    <script>
      function onSubmit() {
        grecaptcha.ready(() => {
            grecaptcha.execute('v3_site_key', {action: 'homepage'}).then((token) => {
               ...
            });
        });
      }
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't it be simplest to just send the token with your form post and double check it server side? I know you're still possibly allowing a bot to post data into your system, but a bot that can sneak by google should be pretty rare. And the first thing your sever side logic should do is verify the token, which can't easily be faked. That said in my initial analysis of google V3(10K requests) the bot detection was solidly binary, in that all the scores were above or below .5 . Google in their documentation recommends different strategies for how to deal with suspicious traffic based on the scenario.

> https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3.

Comment: the invisible v2 recaptcha is what we ended up using, which is kinda what I wanted to achieve in the first place. if it's confident, it lets the visitor through with no problems, otherwise it shows the challenge puzzle.

Comment: @Nnoel could you please share the implementation of the v2 you went with? I'm in the similar boat trying to decide if it'd be better to use a v3 -> v2 approach or a v2 would suffice. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I went with v2's "invisible" option. It decides if it thinks you a robot, and if it does it shows a popup with the challenge puzzle. if you human you've a good chance of not being challenged at all. https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible @bishal

Comment: The main difference between V2 and V3 is in V3 Google gives you a probability score indicating the likely hood of the request being a bot and you decide what your threshold is. On V2 if google thinks you are a bot it will stop you right there. We went with V2 because we didn't want the responsibility of drawing the line of what is and isn't a bot, so we just trusted Google's process.

Comment: "but a bot that can sneak by google should be pretty rare" On our sites (~10 Million unique visitors per day) We see bots beating captcha v2 at around 30%

Comment: @major-mann, at the time I wrote this answer bots getting past recapcha was a rare event on our site. Currently you have to assume recaptcha is not a barrier to bots at all. This is a very dynamic battle and for a while now the bad guys have been winning. Also your results will very by site type. It really is a big mess, there is no silver bullet to blocking bots currently that I am aware of. It seems the current answer is use multiple approaches and hope for the best.

Comment: we have a similar situation in checkout process, but business is not convinced to use v2 captcha due to conversion reasons. I was exactly thinking of combining the v2 and v3 just to have more control over who gets axed in checkout.